# Chaining python conditions together doesn't work as expected

Tags: python

I am trying to test the existence of one of multiple values in an array and it isn't behaving as expected.

```
def valueInList(myList = "abcdefgh"):
    if "a" or "b" in myList:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

For example:

```
>>> valueInList("abc") #should be True
True
>>> valueInList("def") #should be False
True
```

Why isn't this condition working?

Comment: I've added this as a catch-all for the many "why doesn't python understand human readable commands" questions I regularly see.

Comment: There was no need to make a new question, as this is probably the most common Python misconception and has numerous duplicates already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## *Python doesn't use natural language*

While a person can understand `"a" or "b" in myList` the Python interpreter sees it very differently. Adding brackets helps to show this as the next two statements are equivalent:

```
"a"   or  "b" in myList
("a") or ("b" in myList)
```

As such, the condition will always return true as "a" is a Truthy value, that is it isn't False, 0, an empty string or an empty list.